# using a batfile how do I read a line from text file and use the substirng and save it to variabes

Tags: batch-file

I am very new, I have trough a week of tutorial with batch programing and got somewhere.
How ever I still have not figured out this:

my list.txt has lines as

date, name, status, info, comment
exp:
2014-01-01, Jenny, OK, blabaa, nocomment

```
for /f "tokens=* " %%a in (list.txt) do (
    set string=%%a
    call set datearray[i] =%string:~0,10%
    call set namearrat[i]=%string:~12,9%
   call set statusarray[i]=%string:~23,6%
    call set infoarray[i]=%string:~31,3%
  call set comment[i]=%string:~36,4%
```

)

then later do a forloop to write out the items in another batfile

I need help with 2 things:
1) my code is wrong please help with an real example I am new on this
2) how do I get the value out of the arrays ?

I know there are some small answers in the forum but I can not understand them.
Thanks for all help please do explain in real examples so I can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines in list.txt file have fields separated by commas, it is easier to get the tokens via a `for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=,"` command instead of the substrings you use:

```
for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=," %%a in (list.txt) do (
   set datearray[i]=%%a
   set namearray[i]=%%b
   . . .
   set nocomment[i]=%%i
)
```

The right way to store array elements is using DelayedExpansion and enclose the index variable in exclamation marks instead of percents:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set n=0
for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=," %%a in (list.txt) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set datearray[!n!]=%%a
   set namearray[!n!]=%%b
   . . .
   set nocomment[!n!]=%%i
)
```

The way to get out the value of elements is via a `for /L` command to vary the index and enclose the whole element in exclamation marks:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
   echo Date: !datearray[%%i]!, Name: !namearray[%%i]!, etc...
)
```

Further details at: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Comment: Thanks it worked just fine, thanks for that simple explanation.